# C# Linq Query to get between items

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I have a dictionary like this

```
("ABC","X")
("CDE","C")
("EFG","X")
```

I need to retrieve the items which are in **two sides** of `"C"` , How to achieve this with linq ?

**Output Expected** :

**Item = n /  output = (n-1)(n+1) items**

`("ABC","X")` and  `("EFG","X")`

Comment: Tell us the output you expect from the above dictionary and the resulting Linq statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "in two sides of C"?

Comment: So you just want to exclude the "C" item?

Comment: @BrianRogers if Item = n  output = (n-1)(n+1)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Not only exclude i guess, perhaps adjacent?

Comment: Dictionaries do not impose an ordering, so how do we know which one is n-1 and which is n+1 ?

Comment: @BrianRogers: Assume that an OrderBy can be added.  Assume that the beginning order is the order of the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?
Dict.TakeWhile(e => e.Value = "C").Take(1).Reverse().Take(3).

Then remove the middle one.